# How to set Id and name with auto complete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

In Action Class

```
public class Supplier extends ActionSupport{

        private ArrayList supplierList;
       //contains list of supplisers with attribute(id,name,address,mailid)
      //getter and setter of supplierList
    }
```

this is my form(In Jsp)

```
<form action="test" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="supplierName" id="supplierName">
    <input type="hidden" name="supplierId" id="supplierId">
</form>
```

I want to show autocomplete for supplierList's name and based on selected name i want to set its id and name in text and hidden box and on form submission i want to send  id of the element

Comment: I was able to show auto complete only defined at jsp page

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value of the hidden field in the 'select' event of Autocomplete so that when the user selects a name from the autocomplete suggestion list, the hidden field is set to that name's id:

```
$('#textbox-id').autocomplete({
source: // Your ajax call here.

select: function(event, ui){
$('#supplierId').val(ui.item.id);
}
});
```

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Answer (score 0):

You should define a live method with jquery so any time you clicked on one of autocomplete element to set inputs

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('div.supplierItem').live('click', function(){
   $('#supplierId').val($(this).attr('id'));
   $('#supplierName').val($(this).val());
});
</script>

<div class="autoComplete">
   <div class="supplierItem" name="aaa" id="1">
      value1
   </div>
   <div class="supplierItem" name="bbb" id="2">
     value2
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's help you:
1) set attribute class to your autocomplete,
2) find autocomplete with class name

```
 $( elem ).autocomplete({
source: ...}).autocomplete( "widget" ).addClass( "whatever" );
```

It's from http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8928